Inline node styles not being applied to multi-line WBS
I'm building simple org charts using PlantUML & WBS Diagrams, as per documentation: https://plantuml.com/wbs-diagram
I'm trying to apply inline node styles, this works:
@startwbs
<style>
wbsDiagram {
  .highlight {
      BackgroundColor pink
  }
}
node {
    Padding 12
    Margin 30
    HorizontalAlignment center
    LineColor #008AC9
    LineThickness 3.0
    BackgroundColor #A6E1FF
    RoundCorner 10
}
</style>

* John Doe <<highlight>>
** Jane Smith
*** Bob Brown
** Alice Green

@endwbs

Generating:

But when I try to use it with the multi line nodes like so:
@startwbs
<style>
wbsDiagram {
  .highlight {
      BackgroundColor pink
  }
}
node {
    Padding 12
    Margin 30
    HorizontalAlignment center
    LineColor #008AC9
    LineThickness 3.0
    BackgroundColor #A6E1FF
    RoundCorner 10
}
</style>

*:<b>Manager</b> 
John Doe 
<<highlight>>;
**:<b>Lead Developer</b>
Jane Smith;
***:<b>Senior Developer</b>
Bob Brown;
**:<b>QA Lead</b>
Alice Green;

@endwbs

It doesn't work:

How can I apply these styles to individual nodes when using multi line?

Answer pulled from The-Lu on: https://forum.plantuml.net/19353/wbs-diagram-inline-node-styles-with-multiline
@startwbs
<style>
wbsDiagram {
  .highlight {
      BackgroundColor pink
  }
}
node {
    Padding 12
    Margin 30
    HorizontalAlignment center
    LineColor #008AC9
    LineThickness 3.0
    BackgroundColor #A6E1FF
    RoundCorner 10
}
</style>

*:<b>Manager</b>
John Doe; <<highlight>>
**:<b>Lead Developer</b>
Jane Smith;
***:<b>Senior Developer</b>
Bob Brown;
**:<b>QA Lead</b>
Alice Green;

@endwbs

The documentation doesn't cover this case currently.

The-Lu explained to you how to update the docs. I did it here: http://alphadoc.plantuml.com/doc/markdown/en/wbs-diagram#ukaomknmnocfkh6m494b

I hacked out this solution. It's not really multi-line, but I think styles are broken in that mode. You could follow up on the PlantUML Q&A site.
@startwbs
<style>
wbsDiagram {
  .highlight {
      BackgroundColor pink
  }
}
node {
    Padding 12
    Margin 30
    HorizontalAlignment center
    LineColor #008AC9
    LineThickness 3.0
    BackgroundColor #A6E1FF
    RoundCorner 10
}
</style>

* <b>Manager</b>\n\
John Doe <<highlight>>
** <b>Lead Developer</b>\n\
Jane Smith
*** <b>Senior Developer</b>\n\
Bob Brown
** <b>QA Lead</b>\n\
Alice Green

@endwbs


